# Kivy : load_string() vs kv file

Tags: python, kivy

In order to understand the logic behind [Kivy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kivy_(framework)) [kv language](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#how-to-load-kv), I'm trying to rewrite a minimal application by replacing the automatic load of a kv file by a call to Builder.load_string().

---

Here's my starting point ([source: examples 1-2, 1-3](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/creating-apps-in/9781491947333/ch01.html#hello)): two files, *weather.py* and *weather.kv* :

*weather.py:*

```
from kivy.app import App
class WeatherApp(App):
    pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
        WeatherApp().run()
```

and *weather.kv*:

```
Label:
    text: "Hello World"
```

Up to there, everything's alright

[image: result here].

But if I try to load manually the kv stuff, I just get a black screen (and no error message). My code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = '''
Label
    text: "Hello World"
'''
Builder.load_string(KV)

class WeatherApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
        WeatherApp().run()
```

I'm obviously missing something here, but what ? Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create a .kv there are basic but strict rules, among them there can only be one toplevel, the toplevel is identified because it does not have "<>", besides for the App to recognize it it must have the same name of the application in lowercase, in your case the .kv is called ***weather*.kv** and the ***Weather***App app. But the above does not happen if you use Builder, in the case that the .kv has a root as it is in your case `Builder.load_string()` returns it so you must return it in the build method of the App:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = '''
Label:
    text: "Hello World"
'''
root = Builder.load_string(KV)

class WeatherApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
        WeatherApp().run()
```